# Do I need to commit .env files into the repository?

Tags: python, git, virtualenv

I have just started learning backend dev using django. My question is do I just commit the project files in the server folder alone, or should I also commit the `.env` folder to the repository?

I have done the following:

1. I have created virtual environment and I have also installed django in venv.
2. I have setup a django server and super admin.
3. I have setup the `config.json` to protect my API key.
4. Included the same in `.gitignore`.

What happens if I do or do not commit `.env`?

Comment: `.env` files usually mean something like your `config.json`, not "virtuaenv folder".

Answer (score 9):

Assuming that your `.env` folder is your virtual environment, **no you should not commit it**.

The virtual environment should be rebuilt on the server using your `requirements.txt` file. The local environment you built on your development machine may have operating system specific binaries, and other compiled code that was generated for your local environment.

The server will have different compiled binaries, and therefore should rebuild the virtual environment using: `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 9):

You shouldn't commit/include your `.env` file in your git repo because env stands for environment. You will different environment variables for your LOCAL, STAGING(development), PRODUCTION environments.

i.e. your LOCAL .env file might have something like

```
WEB_HOST=localhost
WEB_PORT=8000
ALLOWED_HOSTS=127.0.0.1, localhost
```

but your PRODUCTION .env will have something different like

```
WEB_HOST=www.mysite.com
WEB_PORT=8080
ALLOWED_HOSTS=www.mysite.com
```

Which is why you can't include your .env in your repo and should be created depending on the environment.

Comment: well, you can, but it will not give much value.

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to the documentation you should **not** commit .env file - see https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#should-i-commit-my-env-file.

But it will not hurt much (unless you leak secrets), as on a target environment you will most likely have pre-defined env vars, and values from .env will NOT be used for matching keys.

Sometimes you may even need to "share" env vars with your peers. Of course, you can use the approach defined in the documentation https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#-deploying, but sometimes it is easier to commit .env file.

Just in case to avoid leaking secrets I usually have .env_sample file which has all the necessary keys with content like this:

```
key=<here is your secret>
```

and .env file with the same keys but real values and this file is excluded from source control (git or tfs or whatever you use). By this approach, you give an idea to your peers what your app needs and you don't leak secrets by incident.